# OnClick Sounds stop working after being used to much

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclick

So i'm developing an Android application for school. We've decided to use fragments instead of activities. Anyways my problem that we are currently having is after I put in On click sounds for buttons. They work fine but after you click to many times they no longer make any noise and it stops working in that aspect. What could this be caused by?

Comment: Can you post some code pertaining to what happens when you click the button, and how you are making the sounds?

Comment: Please share code also check Logs for Media Player instance if it is null?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.